# Linux permission in someone else folder?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, multiple-users

If I create some files in a folder with permission 700 in a folder witch is not mine.

The owner of this folder will see it empty and will remove it with my files inside right?

Is there any way to store safely files outside my home directory?

Comment: If they don’t have read permissions then they can’t delete the folder.  If they have access to sudo or root, they can chnage the owner, and it won’t matter

Comment: Also they won’t know if it’s empty or not (assuming they aren’t root), they’ll just see a folder with permission 700 that they don’t have access to.

Comment: note that `rmdir` and `rm -r` will not remove a directory if it has contents. since the other user doesn't have permission to write (or sudo), they cannot delete the file, and thus cannot delete the directory even if they have ownership and permissions to do so. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html  in terms of users with root/sudo, you can only clearly mark your data and tell them to respect your privacy. can't hide from root.